# Rails: simple_form that fills multiple, connected tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have four MySQL tables that should be filled at the same time with a click on a simple_form button. In the form there are input fields for all existing columns from the tables. The domain table has no id for the other tables below, however the others all have a domain_id in their tables. Here are the dependencies:

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :whitelists
    has_many :blacklists
    has_many :product_infos
end

class Whitelist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :domain
end

class Blacklists < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :domain
end

class ProductInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :domain
end
```

My simple_form is stored in the view of domain.

```
<%= simple_form_for @domain do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Example Shop' %>
    <%= f.input :domain, placeholder: 'http://www.example.com' %>

    <h3><b>Whitelist</b></h3>
    <%= f.input :url_start, as: :text %>
    <%= f.input :url_end, as: :text %><br>

    <h3><b>Blacklist</b></h3> 
    <%= f.input :url_start, as: :text %>
    <%= f.input :url_end, as: :text %><br>

    <h3><b>Product Information</b></h3>
    <%= f.input :id_tag %>
    <%= f.input :name_tag %>
    <%= f.input :product_info_text_tag %><br>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My question is how to access the other columns in the view. All inputs besides the ones from domain will lead to an error message (unknown method or local variable). In the models it was quite easy to access attributes from another table, but I can't get behind how it works in the view.

**Edit**: I've now edited the form and the domain controller. However, it still doesn't work. No errors, but only the domain table gets filled.

Domain controller:

```
  def new
    @domain = Domain.new
    @domain.whitelists.build
    @domain.blacklists.build
    @domain.product_infos.build
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_domain
      @domain = Domain.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def domain_params
      params.require(:domain).permit(:whitelist_attributes => [:url_start, :url_end], :blacklist_attributes => [:url_start, :url_end], :product_info_attributes => [:id_tag, :name_tag, :promo_price_tag, :price_tag, :shipping_cost_tag, :image_url_tag, :browse_tree_tag, :product_info_text_tag])
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models) you shoul do like that. Just add `accepts_nested_attributes for :whitelists` and etc.

```
<%= simple_form_for @domain do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Example Shop' %>
    <%= f.input :domain, placeholder: 'http://www.example.com' %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :whitelists do |w| %>

      <%= w.input :url_start, as: :text %>
      <%= w.input :url_end, as: :text %>

    <% end %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :blacklists do |b| %>

      <%= b.input :url_start, as: :text %>
      <%= b.input :url_end, as: :text %>

    <% end %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :products do |p| %>

      <%= p.input :id_tag %>
      <%= p.input :name_tag %>
      <%= p.input :product_info_text_tag %>
    <% end %>    
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

*And in your controller action, add `@domain.whitelists.build` and etc.*

Italic line should be,

`@domain.whitelists.build(params[:whitelists])` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! No error messages this time. However, only the domain table gets filled. In my rails server console there are no errors as well and only the create Domain script will be executed.

Comment: Have you added `params.require(:domain).permit(:whitelist_attributes => [:url_start, :url_end], :blacklist_attributes ...)`  to `domain_params` function inside your DomainsController?

Comment: Now I've added it, but still only the domain table gets filled. Do I have to create a new whitelist/blacklist/product_info object somewhere in the controller?

Comment: if you've already appended `@domain.whitelists.build; @domain.blacklists.build; @domain.product_infos.build;` to the  
 `DomainController`'s new action, below `@domain = Domain.new`, everything should work.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. I've have added parts of the Domain controller in my question. The form is correct, but just too long to be shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! It was a simple solution:

```
params.require(:domain).permit(:whitelist_attributes => [:url_start, :url_end], :blacklist_attributes ...)
```

Every object is singular here, but when I changed it to plural `whitelists_attributes`, `blacklists_attributes`... it worked! Every table gets filled now!